# Creating an event handler from exisiting one

Tags: c#, events, dll, event-handling

I want to create a class library that will contain certain event Handlers. More precisely this library will inherit from a certain dll where various events exist. How can I wrap those events in my own class library?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Maybe give a code example on how this library would be used

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class InnerClass
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}

class WrapperClass
{
    private InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass();

    public event EventHandler SomeEventWrapped
    {
        add { innerClass.SomeEvent += value; }
        remove { innerClass.SomeEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```